# PHP Error: Undefined offset: 10

Tags: php, arrays, forms, debugging, loops

I wrote a program that creates a puzzle based on user's inputs. There is a html form that accepts the user's words and posts them to the php program. Then the php program creates the puzzle and prints it.

There is a live demo [here](http://bit.ly/RFjlVF). You can type you own words.

It looks good but when I run it in my local server with php error prompt turned on, I see the error msg saying `Undefined offset: 10 at line 147 and 148`. The error is generated from the php code line starting from `if ($board[$curr_row][$curr_col] == '.'`... You can use Ctrl+F to find the code. I don't understand how could I get 10 in `$curr_col` or `$curr_row` since the loop should stop after they reach 9.

Please help me understand how could the loop run after they have reached 10, thanks a lot!

The zipped version of the program is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?8kwxngfiv29d0vm).

Here is the code of the php:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php

        /* word Find
         Generates a word search puzzle based on a word list entered by user.
         User can also specify the size of the puzzle and print out
         an answer key if desired
         */
        //If there is no data from the form, prompt the user to go back
        if (!filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "puzzle_name")) {
            print <<<MUL_LINE
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <title>Oops!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This page should not be called directly, please visit 
        the <a href="./form.html">puzzle form</a> to continue.</p>
    </body>
</html>

MUL_LINE;
        } else {
            $boardData = array("name" => filter_input(INPUT_POST, "puzzle_name"), "width" => filter_input(INPUT_POST, "grid_width"), "height" => filter_input(INPUT_POST, "grid_height"));

            if (parseList() == TRUE) {//parse the word list in textarea to an array of words
                //keep trying to fill the board untill a valid puzzle is made
                do {
                    clearBoard();
                    //reset the board
                    $pass = fillBoard();
                } while($pass == FALSE);
                printBoard();
                //if the board if successfully filled, print the puzzle
            }
        }//end word list exists if

        //parse the word list in textarea to an array of words
        function parseList() {
            //get word list, creates array of words from it
            //or return false if impossible

            global $word, $wordList, $boardData;

            $wordList = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "wordList");
            $itWorked = TRUE;

            //convert word list entirely to upper case
            $wordList = strtoupper($wordList);

            //split word list into array
            $word = explode("\n", $wordList);
            //an array of words

            foreach ($word as $key => $currentWord) {
                //trim all the beginning and trailer spaces
                $currentWord = rtrim(ltrim($currentWord));

                //stop if any words are too long to fit in puzzle
                if ((strlen($currentWord) > $boardData["width"]) && (strlen($currentWord) > $boardData["height"])) {
                    print "$currentWord is too long for puzzle";
                    $itWorked = FALSE;
                }//end if
                $word[$key] = $currentWord;
            }//end foreach
            return $itWorked;
        }//end parseList

        //reset the board by filling each cell with "."
        function clearBoard() {
            //initialize board with a . in each cell
            global $board, $boardData;

            for ($row = 0; $row < $boardData["height"]; $row++) {
                for ($col = 0; $col < $boardData["width"]; $col++) {
                    $board[$row][$col] = ".";
                }//end col for loop
            }//end row for loop
        }//end clearBoard

        //fill the board
        function fillBoard() {
            global $word;
            $pass = FALSE;
            //control the loop of filling words, false will stop the loop
            //control the loop, if all the words are filled, the counter will be as equal to the number
            //of elements in array $words, thus the loop stops successfully
            $counter = 0;

            do {

                $pass = fillWord($word[$counter]);
                //if a word is filled, $pass is set to true
                $counter++;

            }
            //if a word can't be filled, pass==FALSE and loop stops
            //or if all words are through, loop stops
            while($pass==TRUE && $counter<count($word));

            //return TRUE if all filled successfully, FALSE if not
            if ($pass == TRUE && $counter == count($word)) {
                return TRUE;
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        //function used to fill  a single word
        function fillWord($single_word) {
            global $board, $boardData;
            //the direction of how the word will be filled, 50% chance to be H, and 50% chance to be V
            $dir = (rand(0, 1) == 0 ? "H" : "V");
            //H(horizontal) means fill the word from left to right
            //V(vertical) means fill the word from up to down
            //loop control. if a letter is not filled, $pass is set to false and loop stops
            $pass = TRUE;
            //loop control. if all letters are filled successfully, loop stops too.
            $counter = 0;

            //decide the cell to fill the first word. the cell is located at $board[$curr_row][$curr_col]
            if ($dir == "H") {//if the word will be fileld from left to right
                $curr_row = rand(0, $boardData["height"] - 1);
                //pick up a random row of the 10 rows ( rand(0,9) )
                $curr_col = rand(0, ($boardData["width"] - ( strlen($single_word - 1)) - 1));
                //pick up a random column of fillable columns
                //if the word is "banana" and the board's width
                //is 10, the starting column can only be rand(0, 4)
            } else if ($dir == "V") {//if the word will be fileld from up to down
                $curr_row = rand(0, ($boardData["height"] - ( strlen($single_word - 1)) - 1));
                $curr_col = rand(0, $boardData["width"] - 1);
            } else {
                print "invalid direction";
            }

            //the loop that keeps trying to fill letters of the word
            while ($pass && ($counter < strlen($single_word))) {//while the $pass is true AND there are still letters

                //to fill, keep the loop going

                //the next line and the line after generate the msg "Undefined offset: 10",
                //$curr_row and $curr_col should never be 10 because the loop should be stopped
                //if the last letter of the word is filled
                if ($board[$curr_row][$curr_col] == '.' || //if the cell is not filled, reset fillboard() to "."
                $board[$curr_row][$curr_col] == substr($single_word, $counter, 1))//or it has already been filled with the same letter
                {
                    $board[$curr_row][$curr_col] = substr($single_word, $counter, 1);
                    // write/fill the letter in the cell
                    $counter++;
                    if ($dir == "H") {
                        $curr_col++;
                        //next column, move to the next right cell
                    } else if ($dir == "V") {
                        $curr_row++;
                        //next row, move to the next lower cell
                    } else {
                        print "\nHuge direction error!";
                    }

                } else {
                    $pass = FALSE;
                    // failed to fill a letter, stop the loop
                }
            }
            //if all the letters are filled successfully, the single word is filled successfully
            //return true, let $fillBoard go filling next single word
            if ($pass && ($counter == strlen($single_word))) {
                /* for debug purpose
                 print "<hr />";print "<p>TRUE</p>";print "<hr />";
                 print $single_word;
                 print $curr_row . "," . $curr_col . "<br />";
                 print "<hr />";*/

                return TRUE;
            } else {
                //failed to fill the word, reset the board and start all over again
                return FALSE;
            }

        }//end function fillWord

        //print the successful filled puzzle
        function printBoard() {
            global $board;
            print <<<MULLINE
    <style type="text/css">
    table, td{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    </style>
MULLINE;
            print '<table >';
            foreach ($board as $row) {
                print '<tr>';
                foreach ($row as $cell) {
                    print '<td>';
                    print $cell;
                    print '</td>';

                }
                print("<br />");
                print '</tr>';
            }
            print "</table>";
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing you need to do, is find out which variable is reaching 10. Don't guess. For example: `if (!isset($board[$curr_row][$curr_col])) {echo $curr_row; echo $curr_row;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the following fragment of code is right.

```
strlen($single_word - 1)
```

located in the lines:

```
$curr_col = rand(0, ($boardData["width"] - ( strlen($single_word - 1)) - 1));
```

and

```
$curr_row = rand(0, ($boardData["height"] - ( strlen($single_word - 1)) - 1));
```

It will convert the word to an integer. Subtract one from that number. Then convert that back to a string and take the length. So you have a rubbish value for the length.

Comment: Ya you are right. I fixed that to `$curr_col = rand(0, ($boardData["width"] - ( strlen($single_word) -1) - 1));`, which was I what I meant originally. Now there are no errors! Thanks! :D